# PowerPoint - Retain the animtion of shapes in a group

Tags: vba, animation, vsto, powerpoint, shapes

Normally we can set animation to shapes. However, when these images are put in group, all the animation is lost. Is there a way to keep the animation of each shapes in a group?

Comment: Think of a group as a single object. You can't animate "just parts of an object" - that is not how animation works. I think the short answer is "no".

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of (and it works for me) is to animate each one of them after they are grouped.